# es6 nested Parallel loop in for-of loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

So I have a array (sources) with nested arrays (sources.feed), sources should be run in Series (one after the other) and sources.feed should be ran in parallel.

I have achieved to run them both in serial:

```
 for (const source of sources) {
     for (const feed of source.feeds) {
         await ProcessService.getData(feed, source)
     }
   }
console.log('Done processing.') //Triggers at the end (as expected)
```

And this is my last of several attempts:

```
for (const source of sources) {
   await Promise.all(source.feeds.map(async (feed) => {
      await ProcessService.getData(feed, source)
   }))
}
console.log('Done processing.') //Triggers before it is done
```

**Updated for clarity (should only be calling ProcessService.getData())**

```
getData: async function(data, source) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
          ...
          resolve()
      } catch(e) {
          reject(e)
      }
   })
 }
```

Comment: In your first code block (which you said works, but in series) you're calling `ProcessService.getData`, but in your second you're calling `RSSService.getRssAsync`. Does `RSSService.getRssAsync` return a promise?

Comment: Corrected. It should be ProcessService

Comment: But still `getRssAsync` instead of `getData`?

Comment: Just fixed and added a brief version of getData()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` to accomplish this.

Waiting for each series:

```
for (const source of sources) {
    const promises = [];

    for (const feed of source.feeds) {
        promises.push(ProcessService.getData(feed, source));
    }

    // Wait for the series to finish before continuing
    await Promise.all(promises);
}
console.log('Done processing.');
```

Waiting for all nested items at the end:

```
const promises = [];
for (const source of sources) {
    for (const feed of source.feeds) {
        promises.push(ProcessService.getData(feed, source));
    }
}

// Wait for all of them at the end (instead of each series)
await Promise.all(promises);
console.log('Done processing.');
```

Comment: `map` is more idiomatic, though. Also note that you're processing the sources in parallel as well as the feeds. The question says the sources have to be processed in series.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I used traditional loops because that's what OP used and switching to `map` didn't seem particularly relevant. I updated my post to include both ways.

Answer (score 3):

In your first code block (which you said works, but in series) you're calling `ProcessService.getData`, but in your second you're calling `RSSService.getRssAsync`.

If I assume that you meant to use `ProcessService.getData` and that it returns a promise (which I figure it must, you said your first code block works as expected), then to make the feeds parallel you'd do something *like* your second code block, but it doesn't have to be quite so complicated:

```
for (const source of sources) {
    await Promise.all(source.feeds.map(feed => ProcessService.getData(feed, source)));
}
console.log('Done processing.');
```

Since `ProcessService.getData` returns a promise, and what we want for `Promise.all` is an array of promises, we don't make the callback `async`, we just use the promise `ProcessService.getData` gives us.

That loops through the sources in series, getting all of the feeds for the first source (in parallel), then all of the feeds of the next source (in parallel), etc.

Live Example:

```js
(async () => {
    const ProcessService = {
        getData(data, source) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    try {
                        console.log(`Done with feed ${source.name} ${data}`);
                        resolve(/*...should have data here...*/)
                    } catch(e) {
                        reject(e)
                    }
                }, Math.random() * 500);
            });
        }
    }

    const sources = [
        {name: "Source 1", feeds: ["11", "12", "13"]},
        {name: "Source 2", feeds: ["21", "22", "23"]},
        {name: "Source 3", feeds: ["31", "32", "33"]},
        {name: "Source 4", feeds: ["41", "42", "43"]}
    ];

    for (const source of sources) {
        console.log(`Processing ${source.name}`);
        await Promise.all(source.feeds.map(feed => ProcessService.getData(feed, source)));
    }
    console.log('Done processing.');
})().catch(e => {
    console.error(`Error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

If you really need to use `RSSService.getRssAsync`, it would appear it doesn't return a promise, since if it did your code would have worked as expected (even though it could be simpler). To convert a callback API to a promise API see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises?r=SearchResults&s=1|410.9849).

---

Your `getData` function has a couple of issues:

1. Since you're explicitly creating a promise, it shouldn't be an `async` function. You use an `async` function when you want to use `await` on an **existing** promise. If you're creating a new promise, you almost never wan an `async` function.
2. The function you pass into `new Promise` (the *promise executor function*) should **never** be `async`.
3. You're showing that you're calling `resolve()` with no argument. That's okay if you really mean to fulfill the promise with the value `undefined` (which there are some limited use cases for), but if the function is called `getData`, it really should return data, not `undefined`.

So:

```
getData: function(data, source) {
//       ^---- no `async` here
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//                     ^---- no `async` here
      try {
          ...
          resolve(/*...should have data here...*/)
      } catch(e) {
          reject(e)
      }
   })
}
```

Also note that you can use method syntax (this appears to be within an object initializer):

```
getData(data, source) {
//     ^
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
          ...
          resolve(/*...should have data here...*/)
      } catch(e) {
          reject(e)
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: (corrected the question ProcessService is correct) ProcessService.getData returns a "resolve()" or "reject()" with a new Promise(), should I not "resolve()" when its done?

Comment: @galgo - I don't quite follow what you mean by << ProcessService.getData returns a "resolve()" or "reject()"  >>. But if your first code block works as you expect, and you want to do the feeds in parallel, and you're using `ProcessService.getData`, the above will work, getting the feeds for the first source in parallel, then moving on and getting all the feeds for the next source in parallel, etc. Any function returning a promise will also work. If it isn't a function returning a process, see the link at the end of the answer.

Comment: @galgo - If `getData` is as you've shown, the second code block in your question would work. So I don't think it is as shown. There are some issues with it as shown in the question which I've addressed in an update to the answer.

Comment: What if I what to execute a async function inside of the getData like: let feed = await parser.parseURL(data.feed)

Comment: As it is right now, your suggested code, run the for-of, the goes to "Done processing." whilst the Promise(.map) keep running (even after the Done processing.)

Comment: @galgo - No, it doesn't. This does what the answer you accepted did, just in a more idiomatic way. See the live example.